# How do I set breakpoints in Komodo IDE?

Tags: perl, breakpoints, komodo, komodo-ide

I've installed [Komodo IDE](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-ide/) and I would like to know where/how can I set the breakpoints so that 9th symbol on the top line `|>`  understands it ?

[image]

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the line number in the gutter on the left of the code.

[image: screen recording that shows clicking the gutter on a line that outputs a variable, runs the debugger and demonstrates the variable value was set]

Comment: Please see my **EDIT**: I cannot see the `value` of `my variable $f` :-(

Comment: Do I need to have a `print statement` to see the value of my watched variable ??

Comment: @user2925716 your breakpoint in the 2nd screenshot is on the same line as the declaration and the initialisation of the variable. Declaring the variable in its scope happens at run time, so the Perl debugger knows about it (and Komodo can show that). But since you're breaking on that line, that means it's stopped BEFORE the code in that line gets executed at run time. So the value of 2 has not been assigned yet. That's why I put my breakpoint on the statement below that. The `print` has nothing to do with it.