# The value of an ARRAY at a breakpoint is not visible

Tags: perl, ide, breakpoints, komodo

I've asked a related question [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67838860/how-do-i-set-breakpoints-in-komodo-ide) **but** I still would like to know why I do **not see the value** of an array `@x`:

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a chevron or `>` symbol left to `@x`, which probably indicates that you can unfold a tree view and inspect the contents.

Comment: This is basically a screenshot with an insufficient description of your problem. I don't really know what you mean with "I do not see the value of an array @x". I can only guess is that you are confused that you `$y` is 5, i.e. the length of the array and not some of the 5 elements of it (which one did you expect?). This is expected. If you want to have the first element use `($y) = @x` instead.

Comment: You don't see a value for the array because arrays don't have a value. They have elements. You can view these by clicking on `>`. It would be nice if it displayed the number of elements in the array, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on Windows 10, you just need to click the `>` sign in front of the `@x` array to expand the view and show its elements (as noted in the comments by @amon):

[image]

Comment: @user2925716 I think perhaps because your question shows a screenshot of the output you got, but doesn't explain what output you were expecting. Having a good answer doesn't make something a good question. If you edit the question to improve more information about what you were expecting, I think you'll probably find the question will not be closed.

Comment: @tobyink I've explained that I was expecting to see the **value** of my ARRAY `@x`.